# Stream deployment failing with CloudFoundryAppDeployer: Error: Organization does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have deployed data-flow server and skipper successfully on cloud foundry but when I try to deploy stream with all deployer properties configured, it is complaining org doesn't exist.

I have tried to configured different properties from data flow web UI but when I deploy stream it fails with error: org doesn't exist. I gave all cloud foundry credential everything that I provided to skipper and server, which are working fine, just stream inside data flow is not able to understand cloud foundry app deployer properties.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg74Y.jpg)

In the pic above you can see how I am providing properties value to stream from data flow web UI.

I am getting below error message :

> 2019-07-23T09:48:37.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-07-23 13:48:37.509  INFO 9 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.s.s.s.StateMachineConfiguration    : Entering state ObjectState [getIds()=[INSTALL_INSTALL], getClass()=class org.springframework.statemachine.state.ObjectState, hashCode()=444730043, toString()=AbstractState [id=INSTALL_INSTALL, pseudoState=org.springframework.statemachine.state.DefaultPseudoState@49b9c289, deferred=[], entryActions=[org.springframework.cloud.skipper.server.statemachine.InstallInstallAction@6981f8f3], exitActions=[], stateActions=[], regions=[], submachine=null]]
>      2019-07-23T09:48:38.44-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-07-23 13:48:38.440  INFO 9 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.d.s.c.AbstractCloudFoundryDeployer : Preparing to push an application from org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:log-sink-rabbit:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE. This may take some time if the artifact must be downloaded from a remote host.
>      2019-07-23T09:48:41.70-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-07-23 13:48:41.708 ERROR 9 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.d.s.c.CloudFoundryAppDeployer      : Error: Organization RE-Pheonix-DataFlow-NonProd does not exist creating app DAu4sEO-MyStream1-log-v1
>      2019-07-23T09:48:41.72-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-07-23 13:48:41.719 ERROR 9 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.d.s.c.AbstractCloudFoundryDeployer : Failed to deploy DAu4sEO-MyStream1-log-v1
>      2019-07-23T09:48:41.72-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Organization RE-Pheonix-DataFlow-NonProd does not exist
>      2019-07-23T09:48:41.72-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.cloudfoundry.util.ExceptionUtils.illegalArgument(ExceptionUtils.java:45) ~[cloudfoundry-util-3.15.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]

Following is my deploy properties:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg74Y.jpg)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVXKf.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUtGW.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSzzn.png)

Please find exported deploy prop:

[Deployer Prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJtn0.png)

Skipper Config

[Skipper Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKqhu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For the stream deployment, the Cloud Foundry connection properties (org, space, url, username, password, skipSslValidation) are obtained either from the global Skipper configuration properties for the chosen platform or via the deployment properties set when deploying the stream.

You should be able to provide the `org` connection property when deploying the stream like this:

[image: screenshot]

If you don't specify this property as a deployer property when deploying the stream, then the Skipper configuration for the corresponding platform will be used.

Can you share how you configured your Skipper configuration properties for Cloud Foundry connection for the chosen platform?

Comment: I did configuration by following : https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/cloudfoundry/cf-cli/

Which is working fine for server and skipper but not for application startup by skipper.

Comment: Can you export and share what you pass as deployment properties (after redacting)?

Comment: updated original question with images of deployment properties. I think when skipper is starting application it is not looking into deployment prop.

Comment: Let me try to understand the problem here. I see that the org `RE-Pheonix-DataFlow-NonProd` is set. Is this what you set in Skipper as the CF connection property? and, whatever you set as CF deployer property for `org` is not overriding the one from Skipper? Can you also post how you pass the deployer property (there is an option to export the deployer properties to a text file from the UI) ?

Comment: updated with skipper config and exported deployer config, so far I feel like deployer is able to get correct org but doesn't know connection url or username or password.. some prop is missing.,,...

Comment: please let me know if you need more information, thanks for helping on this

Comment: After some investigation, I think this (the CF connection properties are not overridable)  is a bug. Created an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry/issues/298. Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Got it, thank for investigation for me but is there any work around to give connection prop to deployer, because I am working on POC to make this thing working.. can deployer get connection prop from skipper?

Comment: Yes of course. I thought you were trying to override your `org` property via deployer with the one that is already set in Skipper.  The deployer eventually gets the connection property from Skipper. It is just that you can not override what is already defined in Skipper.

Comment: great.. it worked without providing deploy cloud connection prop, it has used skipper connection prop. thanks for you help....